# SQL Data load - Suggestions required

Tags: sql, ssis, bulkinsert

Gurus,

We are in process of setting up a SSIS package to load a formatted text file in to SQL server. It will have around 100 million rows and file size will be (multiple files of around 15 GB each) 100 GB. The file format is aligned with XML schema like mentioned below... it takes nearly 72 hrs to load this file in to SQL server tables...

**File format**

EM|123|XYZ|30|Sales mgr|20000|AD|1 Street 1| State1|City1|US|AD|12Street 2|state 2|City2|UK|CON|2012689648|CON|42343435

EM|113|WYZ|31|Sales grade|200|AD|12 Street 1| State2|City2|US|AD|1Street 22|state 3|City 3|UK|CON|201689648|CON|423435

EM|143|rYZ|32|Sales Egr|2000|AD|113Street 1| State3|City3|US|AD|12Street 21|state 4|City 5|UK|CON|201269648|CON|443435

Data will come in above format. It means "EM" till "AD" is Employee details like Code,Name,age,Designation,Salary and "AD" is Address details like Street,Sate,City,Country. Address data can be multiple for same employee...similarly "CON" is contact details with Phone number which also may be multiple.

So, we need to load Employee Details in to seperate table, Address details in seperate table and Contact details in seperate table with Code as Primary key in Employee Details and Reference key in other two tables.

We designed package like, had a Script Component as Source and parsed line by line by using .NET scripts and created multiple out put buffers each per table and added the row in the script. Mapped the Script component output to 3 OLE DB Destinations (SQL Server tables).

Our server is Quad Core with 48 GB RAM virtualized and we have 2 cores with 24 GB dedicated for DB. Our SQL server DB (Simple Recovery model) has Data files in Network share location that is SAN storage. To improve performance we created Each table in differenct data file (Primary and secondary).. but still it takes around 72 hrs.

Need guidance on following points.

1. Is it possible to use BCP, if yes any pointers.. (Hope BCP will perform better)
2. Any suggestions on specified solution.
3. Any alternates...

There are no indexes defined on the table also no triggers...We have even set defaultMaxbufferzie to 100 MB

Looking forward for response..Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: What's the question?  How to make this faster?  Did you disable indexes before loading?

Comment: Definitely check if indexes are on and also if you have some funky triggers or other objects in place on the destination tables.

Comment: Step 1, throw away your source script, unless you feel confident that your team has written tighter code than the out of the box flat file component. Use the Multicast if you need to send to multiple destination. Could you clarify what you mean by "added the row in the script." Perhaps an example of expected results for your 3 tables given the supplied input data would be beneficial.

Comment: Copy your files to a local location before performing the import and parallelize your package design. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd795221(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Flat file component will not help for parsing our file format...We don't have any cocntrol on file creation... if there is a better way to do this let us know...

Comment: Saravanan, if you hook up your script component to a conditional split and simply run the import of the files, how long does it take?  this will tell us how fast your script is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) If necessary, simplify/flatten your XML file via XSLT as shown here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/12/15/xml-source-making-things-easier-with-xslt.aspx

2.) Use XML Source as shown here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/12/11/using-xml-source.aspx

3.) Drop any indexes on the destination tables

4.) If your source data is bulletproof, disable constraints on the tables via:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

5.) Load the data via OLEDB Destination

6.) Re-enable constraints

7.) Re-create indexes

Answer (score 0):

You say the data files are on a network share. One improvement would be to add a hard drive and run the job on the SQL server as you'd eliminate latency. I think even hooking up a USB drive to read the files from would be better than using a network location. Certainly worth a little test in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is pretty quick when doing bulk loads, so I suspect that the bottleneck isn't with SSIS itself, but something about the way your database/server is configured. Some suggestions:

- When you're running the import, how many rows are you importing every second (you can do a "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WITH READUNCOMMITTED" during the import to see) Does this rate stay constant, or does it slow down towards the end of your import?
- As others have said, do you have any indexes or triggers on your destination tables?
- While you're running the import, what do your disks look like? In perfmon, is the disk queue spiking like crazy, indicating that your disks are the bottleneck? What's the throughput on these disks during normal performance testing? I've had experience where improperly configured iSCSI or improperly aligned SAN storage can drop my disks from 400MB/s down to 15MB/s - still fine during regular usage, but way too slow to do anything in bulk.

You're also talking about loading 100GB of data, which is no small amount - it shouldn't take 72 hours to load, but it won't load it in 20 minutes either, so have reasonable expectations. Please weigh in on these and the other bottlenecks people have asked about and we may be able to help you isolate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the way the files are created to begin with, I would move away from the one-to-many relationship you have with the `|EM|` and `|AD|`,`|CON|` and do something like this:

`|EM|EmpID|data|data|`

`|AD|EmpID|data|data|`

`|CON|EmpID|data|data|`

Further, if you can split the records into three different files, you'd be able to use a Flat File Source component with a fixed specification for each source to process the data in bulk.